# Merge SQL Table rows based on zeros

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me query this table

```
11:00 | 5 | 0 |0 |0
11:00 | 0 | 4 |0 |0
11:00 | 0 | 0 |3 |0
11:00 | 0 | 0 |0 |8
11:05 | 7 | 0 |0 |0
11:05 | 0 | 2 |0 |0
11:05 | 0 | 0 |6 |0
11:05 | 0 | 0 |0 |4
```

To:

```
11:00 | 5 | 4 |3 |8
11:05 | 7 | 2 |6 |4
```

You can safely assume that each row has only one value greater then 0.
To make it easy to test, here's the table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Time NVARCHAR(10), Value1 INT, Value2 INT, Value3 INT, Value4 INT)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('11:00',5,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('11:00',0,4,0,0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('11:00',0,0,3,0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('11:00',0,0,0,8)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('11:05',7,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('11:05',0,2,0,0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('11:05',0,0,6,0)
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('11:05',0,0,0,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Time, 
       max(Value1) as value1,
       max(Value2) as value2,
       max(Value3) as value3,
       max(Value4) as value4
from MyTable 
group by Time
```